# How to read specific characters in python 2.7.6 in a specific line?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have this text written in line number 5

```
" Name: Roger Federer
```

how can I go to line number 5 first and then read and print out "Roger Federer" instead of the whole line.I am not getting how to use the file.seek function in this case.

Comment: You don't need `file.seek()`. Just do `for line in file:` and count to 5.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use `file.seek` here since it takes *bytes* as an argument. Just use what you know:

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as somefile:
    lines = somefile.readlines()

roger_federer_line = lines[4]   # 5th line
print(roger_federer_line[6:])   # print 6th character onwards
```

This assumes your file line says `Name: Roger Federer`. If it has `"` at the beginning of the line you should use 8 instead of 6.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the entire file into memory using `readlines()` (just for reading the single 5-th line), iterate over the file object line-by-line and stop (`break`) on the 5-th line:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:  
    for number, line in enumerate(f):
        if number == 4:
            print(line.split(':')[-1].strip())
            break
```

Note: getting `Roger Federer` out of `" Name: Roger Federer` by splitting the string by `:` and getting the last element, `strip()` helps to omit new-lines and unwanted leading and trailing spaces:

```
>>> line = " Name: Roger Federer"
>>> print(line.split(':')[-1].strip())
Roger Federer
```